# Split a String into two text boxes

Tags: javascript, string, asp-classic

How would I separate a generated number that always starts with two letters and then a series of digits (e.g. ab123456) into two strings, and then put them into two text boxes?

The number is generated using a JavaScript method.

in number is stored in a `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="usernumber" class="usera"></div>
```

It needs to be written into two text boxes like this:

```
Response.Write("<td width=\"50%\"><input type=\"text\" id = \"userdepartment\"  name=\"department\" size=\"3\" maxlength=\"2\"> <input type=\"text\" id = \"usernumber\" name=\"number\" size=\"10\" disp=\"Department Number\" maxlength=\"6\">\n");
```

Comment: You would do it by writing the pertinent code. What have you written so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have code up to that point genreating the number, however I just need needed the fundamental why of going about it, therefore I didnt post my code, because I dont want it written for me, rather im looking for the technique. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I wasn't concerned. Just pointing out the fact that your question shows no effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Gotcha, thats understandable

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much information so this'll likely answer just one part of your question. Splitting your string into two parts and putting into two different text boxes.

There are other solutions to split a compound string based on your requirements. This one uses a **regular expression** but you could use `slice` or `substr` just as well:

```
var s = "ab123456";
var rx = /([a-z]{2})(\d+)/i;

if (rx.test(s))
{
    var split = rx.exec(s);
    var letters = split[1];
    var number = split[2];

    document.getElementById("box1").value = letters;
    document.getElementById("box2").value = number;
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("box1").value document.getElementById("box2").value`

Comment: Nothing. Just copy/pasting text.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `.slice()` to get the first two characters and then the characters.
- Use `document.getElementById()` to fetch your boxes. *(Make sure they have IDs)*
- Assign the strings to the `.value` property of the boxes.

---

```
document.getElementById("box1").value = mystring.slice(0,2);
document.getElementById("box2").value = mystring.slice(2);
```

---

For your updated question, if the number is the text content of the `<div>`, do this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var text = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

    var number = document.getElementById("usernumber")[text];


    document.getElementById("userdepartment").value = number.slice(0,2);
    document.getElementById("usernumber").value = number.slice(2);
};
```

Comment: everything i have tried doesnt seem to want to put it into the value of the box

Comment: @peppertini: I updated my answer. Give it a try. I'm assuming the number string is stored in the content of the `<div>`.

Comment: you are correct its stored in a div that is populated by another js function